# How to find wifi signal strength in Windows RT or 8.1 Application Store Apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have some issues in Windows 8.1 store apps, i want app event if wifi signal strength  change, your answers will be appreciated

Comment: In Windows runtime, the [WiFiAvailableNetwork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiavailablenetwork.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class has an property [SignalBars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiavailablenetwork.signalbars.aspx) which can get the strength of the signal as a number of bars. The current number of signal bars displayed by Windows UI for the network.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of NetworkConnection class present inside the Windows.Networking.Connectivity namespace and use the ConnectionProfile class which has method called GetSignalBars which gives nullable byte from value 0 to 5.

```
var strength = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetSignalBars();
```

More details about signal strength can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getsignalbars). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi CodeNoob, i already used the above code, but i want an event if wifi signal  strength change automatically triggered,

Comment: There is not event for that purpose. Other way could be to use an interval timer and call the above mentioned code at specific intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I cannot see any events for you to detect Wifi Signal Strength Changes. What I can think is to repeat reading the data in your app use dispatcher timer. More detail about building a Wi-Fi Scanner in the UWP you could refer to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736460.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

absolutely you can get signal bars but question is how to update network strength

i have answer for (i can provide exactly what should you if you provide xaml and c# code)..
now all you have to do use "DispatcherTimer" which will update your signal strength time to time.
  use this code in your page initialization or app.xaml.cs initialization

```
using System.Windows.Threading;



DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

timer.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   // use your wifi class etc. e.g this.SignalStrengthProgressBar.Value = (FMRadio.Instance.SignalStrength); this is example for fm radio in wp8.
};

timer.Start();
```

here timespan.fromsecond(1) 1 is second adjust second according to your need because time update will suck your battery

like my answer ? upvote and mark as answer